# Cant run firefox on ubuntu via command

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, firefox

I have the following script via which I install Firefox on a Heroku instance. For whatever reason, the script doesn't properly associate firefox with the right path even though the path does exist.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

BUILD_DIR=$1
CACHE_DIR=$2

# config
VERSION=58.0.1
LANG=en-US
PLATFORM=linux64
# PLATFORM=linux

# Buildpack URL
ARCHIVE_NAME=firefox

FILE_NAME=${ARCHIVE_NAME}-${VERSION}.tar.bz2

BUILDPACK_FIREFOX_PACKAGE="https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US"

mkdir -p $CACHE_DIR
if ! [ -e $CACHE_DIR/$FILE_NAME ]; then
  echo "-----> Fetching Firefox package from ${BUILDPACK_FIREFOX_PACKAGE}"
  curl $BUILDPACK_FIREFOX_PACKAGE -L -o $CACHE_DIR/$FILE_NAME
fi

echo "-----> Extracting Firefox binaries to ${BUILD_DIR}/vendor/${ARCHIVE_NAME}"
mkdir -p $CACHE_DIR/$ARCHIVE_NAME
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR/vendor
tar jxf $CACHE_DIR/$FILE_NAME -C $BUILD_DIR/vendor/

echo "-----> exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH"
PROFILE_PATH="$BUILD_DIR/.profile.d/firefox.sh"
mkdir -p $(dirname $PROFILE_PATH)
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/vendor/firefox"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:vendor/firefox"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
```

So after installing Firefox the following way, I can't run it.

If I do 
`which firefox`

output is:
`/app/vendor/firefox/firefox`

If I do 
`whereis firefox`

output is:
`firefox: /app/vendor/firefox/firefox /app/vendor/firefox/firefox.sig`

If I do `./firefox`

output is:
`bash: /app/vendor/firefox/firefox: No such file or directory`

But the file definitely exists because

```
~/vendor/firefox $ pwd
/app/vendor/firefox
~/vendor/firefox $ ls -l
-rwx------ 1 u5487 dyno   206820 Jan 28 20:23 firefox
```

I read somewhere that I need to do a symlink, but is there any way that I can get this to work without it? Either in the shell script itself or somehow differently?

`file firefox`

```
firefox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=f8af6497e4ec47fd4bd584917a78f224f88baee, stripped
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the executable's dynamic linker. Check with `ldd`

Comment: @thatotherguy I get `~/vendor/firefox $ ldd firefox` `not a dynamic executable`. How do I fix this? Sorry, I'm a complete newbie in this.

Comment: Check `file firefox` to see what it is. If `ldd` doesn't like it, it might be for a different architecture.

Comment: @thatotherguy Updated the question with the relevant info (`file firefox`), I assume all is looking good :(

Comment: If you do `/app/vendor/firefox/firefox` (specify the complet path) , does firefox start? Also, what strikes me is the `PLATFORM=linux64` in the script and the `32-bit LSB executable` as output in the file command.

Comment: If you want to run a 32bit program on a 64bit system, you need 32bit versions of all the relevant libraries (including the linker).

Comment: @LjmDullaart Nope it does not. I've changed the link to be linux64, but to no avail :(

Comment: @thatotherguy I want to run 64 on a 64bit platform. I'm unsure what's wrong, but I've fixed the link.

Comment: @BorkoKovacev Please make sure the rest of the post is also up to date

Comment: the problem is, that the file is not found. It is not that the file is not executable, or that it has the wrong format or things like that. it says `No such file or directory`. I do not understand your comment "I've fixed the link". If you use the complete path, does it also complain `No such file or directory` or do you get a different error message?